# How to create a GIS basemap in R?

Tags: r, gis

I am an expert GIS user moving towards R more and more.  I have been using R for some basic regressions and such, but I would like to begin to use and manipulate GIS data in R.

How can I create a basemap graphic similar to the one in this post:
[Showing spatial and temporal correlation on maps](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72421/showing-spatial-and-temporal-correlation-on-maps)

Again, I am a beginner in R and haven't found any other related thread here.

Comment: There are several people on [gis.se] actively using `R` for their work: consider [searching the site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=votes). Certainly you will want to take a look at ["How to make beautiful maps in R"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48828).

Comment: Welcome to the site, @mikeLdub. This question seems to be *only* about how to do this in R. As such, it may be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)); but could be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a question about the substantive statistical / visualization issues, please edit to clarify; if not we will migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*). If it does go to SO, it will need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) to be on-topic there; can you add a `dput()` of your data?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about how to use R.

Comment: If you want, post a question to Stackoverflow and I'll answer there. It's only a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

R by itself does not handle GIS type of work but with different add-ons it can be a quite potent GIS device. You'd need to understand the idea of "package" (user-contributed scripts) and how to use `install.packages("whateverPackage")` command to install them.

I don't use R in GIS enough to show you the whole topography (pun totally intended), but the most commonly used packages I have seen are `map`, `ggmap`, `ggplot2`, `RgoogleMaps`, and `plotGoogleMap`.

Also, check out some sites and tutorials about this topic: [1](http://www.nyu.edu/projects/politicsdatalab/workshops/GISwR.pdf), [2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html), [3](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf), and [4](http://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/web/packages/plotGoogleMaps/vignettes/plotGoogleMaps-intro.pdf). These got me started and within a day I could make some silly maps.

Lastly, this [pdf](http://statacumen.com/teach/SC1/SC1_16_Maps.pdf) probably contains some codes pertinent to the map you wish to create. Its $\LaTeX$ format is a bit off, but you can still get some general functionality and key commands.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should read through the Spatial and possibly SpatialTemporal [Taskviews on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/).  Those will give you an idea of what packages are available and gives brief descriptions of what they do and how they compare.